# Postgres Trigger?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

For each query I am sending to any of the tables, I want it to automatically create the same query to a clone of that table.

For example, 
I have a sales_invoice table. Each insert/update/delete will trigger an insert into sales_invoice_clone table. Also I want it to add a text to the comment field of the clone table upon trigger. The comment will either be "insert operation", "update operation", or "delete operation".

How do I do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I am still a noob in postgres, so if you can help with a simple example, it will give me some light to try it out

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PostgreSQL triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html). See the documentation for further details or show the code you already have and where you're stucked.

[Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) is the description of how to trigger procedures.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_clone AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON your_table
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE clone();
```

where clone is your procedure to clone the operation. Otherwise think about a replication?